# 400 amp electrical service

Tags: electrical

I need to make a service for a duplex that I use to feed my 400amp service.

What gauge wire do you recommend for either aluminum and copper? Also, do you recommend one or the other?[image]

Comment: Beware buying that stuff on Amazon. Talk to your local electrical supply houses (For one thing they'll get you the right thing, which this ain't). Electrical gear on Amazon is basically sucker pricing, because either you get beat up on shipping (they build shipping into pricing for Prime members' sake) or it's highballers hoping you won't notice or care.  Hit at least 3 electrical supplies and ask for trade pricing, one of my local ones likes to charge full retail...

Comment: What state are  you in? This one is a darling for local amendments.   Also, where specifically will this wire be running, what route through the building to the service drop or lateral?  Straight upward to the service drop pole?

Comment: I agree with Harper. Buying basic wiring stuff (wiring, receptacles, etc) isn't bad on Amazon (I was shocked to get Romex at nearly half the price of my local big box) but I would never buy a service entrance until from them. Amazon will gladly sell you anything... even if you don't need it.

Comment: Who is your electric utility? Also, is this an overhead or an underground service?

Comment: Furthermore, are there any loads that are *shared* between the two halves of this duplex (such as a yard light), and what does it already have for an electrical service?